# Finding the affine equation of a plane given three points

Tags: linear-algebra

First of all, I am not sure the correct word is "affine" in english however it is "affin" in Swedish and I can't find the english counterpart. Affine form is basically the non-parametric equation of a plane: a

$$ax + by + cz + d = 0$$

I am given three points:

$$P:(1,2,0)$$ 
$$Q:(-1,3,1)$$ 
$$R:(-1,1,2)$$

and asked to find the "non-parametric" equation for the plane.

My attempt is to simply solve the system of equations: 
$$ax + by + cz + d = 0$$

$$\begin{cases} 
a + 2b + d = 0
\\
-a + 3b + c + d = 0
\\
-a+b+2c+d = 0
\end{cases}$$

The process is quite tedious so I won't bore you with it, but I know it's correct and I end up with:

$$
\begin{cases}
a = -2b-d
\\
b = ?
\\c=2b
\\
d=-\frac{7}{2}b
\end{cases}
$$

There is too many unknown variables too solve the system of equations, but in my book the author simply assigns $b = 2$ and solves it. Why can this be done?

Comment: It's called Cartesian equation of a plane.

Comment: The degree of freedom is from scaling the equation $ax+but+cz+d=0$.  So, you can choose any value you wish.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forming equation of a plane by solving linear equation set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150678/forming-equation-of-a-plane-by-solving-linear-equation-set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cartesian equation of a plane in $\Bbb R^3$ can neatly be expressed as $\vec n\cdot\vec x=\vec n\cdot\vec x_0$ where $\vec n$ is a vector normal to the plane, $\vec x=\langle x,y,z\rangle$, and $\vec x_0$ is a point on the plane. In our case, the two directions
\begin{align*}
\vec{PQ} &= \langle -2,1,1\rangle & \vec{PR} &= \langle-2,-1,2\rangle
\end{align*}
are both in the plane. Therefore we may take 
$$
\vec n=\vec{PQ}\times\vec{PR}=\langle3,2,4\rangle
$$
We may also take $\vec x_0=P$. This gives 
$$
3\,x+2\,y+4\,z=7
$$

Comment: This is another method. It does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Apparently the OP disagrees with you (eight years ago)...

Comment: Yes I saw that the OP contradicted him or herself, which I find wrong towards the other answerers and the at-that-time-future readers.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the parameters that describe the plane are not unique. If $ax+by+cz+d=0$ then also $2ax+2by+2cz+2d=0$. Of course the $2$ there could be any non-zero real number.

The work you did shows us that if $b=0$ then all of $a$, $c$ and $d$ would also be zero. This shows that in case of this particular plane $b$ cannot be zero. And by the earlier argument we can choose it arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

$$
P-Q = (2,-1,-1) \\
Q-R=(0,2,-1) \\
\hat n = (P-Q)\times (Q-R) =(3,2,4)
$$
now
$$
(\hat r - Q)\cdot\hat n = 0
$$
i.e.
$$
3x+2y+4z=7
$$

Comment: This is another method. It does not answer the OP's question.