# How to find the equation of a plane passing through the intersection point of three planes and the origin and another point.

Tags: analytic-geometry

Determine the equation of the plane that passes through the point of intersection of the planes
$$P=\begin{cases}
2x + z - 7 = 0\\
 x - y = 0\\
x + y - 2z + 2=0 
\end{cases}$$
and passes through the origin and the point $Q=(2, 3, 8)$.
I tried a lot to find the solution of this problem but in vain.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you. This is not a homework service.

Comment: I searched for the way to solve such that problem in a lot of sites and books but I didn't find the answer for my question.

Comment: Do you mean the intersection point of the three planes?

Comment: Ok, P=(2, 2, 3) what should I do after that?

Comment: It is Ax + By + Cz + D =0 where A, B, C are direction ratios perpendicular to the plane and D is the length of the column falling form the origin to the plane.

Comment: These points must achieve the equation of the plane that means by substituting for these points in the equation of a plane passing through three points we get the equation of the required plane.

Comment: Well, do that and tell us the 3 equations on $a,b,c,d$ you obtain. Then, solve this system. You will find $d=0$ and (for instance) $b=$ a certain number times $c$ and $a=$ another number times $c.$

Comment: The three equations are:(1) 2A + 2B + 3C=0 (2) Ax + By + Cz=0 (3) 2A + 3B + 8C=0

Comment: I agree with (1) and (3) but not with (2), I don't know where you took it from. Before (1) and (3), you seem to have noticed that $d=0$ is the condition for $O$ to belong to the plane. So, our 3 equations are (0): $d=0$ and your (1) and (3). Now, solve [(1)and(3)] like I hinted before.

Comment: Sorry I mean that the three equations are:(1) 2A + 2B + 3C + D=0 (2) Ax + By + Cz=0 (3) 2A + 3B + 8C + D=0 by solving the three equation we get the equation of the required plane: 7x - 10y + 2z=0

Comment: Your equation (2) makes no sense. There must be no $x,y,z.$ How do you express that $O$ belongs to the plane? And how did you find "the required plane" since you do not have the correct equations?

Comment: That means that D=0 so the plane passes through the origin in this case as it is khown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144900/discussion-between-anne-bauval-and-mohamed-asem).

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585730) the beginning of a chain of 3 duplicates, selected in [this list](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=equation+of+a+plane%2C+given+three+points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick way of solving this.

The required plane must take the form $$2x+z-7+\lambda(x-y)+\mu(x+y-2z+2)=0$$
For some $\lambda, \mu\in\mathbb{R}$

This is because it is the equation of a plane, and it is satisfied by the point which simultaneously satisfies the equations of all three given planes (i.e. the point of intersection).

Now $(0,0,0)$ lies on the plane, so $\mu=\frac72$.

Also $(2,3,8)$ lies on the plane, so $\lambda=-\frac{53}{2}$

Using these values of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ gives the equation of the plane, which simplifies to $$-7x+10y-2z=0$$

Answer (score -1):

[image]

This is the rule used for finding the equation of any plane passing through three coplinear points.

Comment: I am disappointed: this is not what you planned to do in the chat (and which would have been quicker). But never mind, complete the calculations in this answer. I.e. replace the $x_i,y_i,z_i$ by their values and compute this determinant.

Comment: I tried to show you the way I used for solving the three equation in a method or another and there are no difference in the final result so any method I mentioned it is right.

Comment: I know that method but I tried to teach you a quicker one in the chat, and it was almost finished (you nearly had the final the result with that method), whereas here there still is much work to do.

Comment: Oh I have understood everything, thank you sir.

Comment: It would be good for you to present your end of the resolution, by both methods.